# Move the <path> element to the bottom of its container

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to move an svg to be flush with the bottom of my header background [like this (this is from my Figma design)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTdWl.jpg) but so far I'm unable to cover [this bottom portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3l0r.jpg) of the background with the svg.

The div containing the svg is at the [very bottom of it's container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Iimc.jpg) so its just the *path* element that [needs to be moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXN9e.jpg)

So far, I've tried setting formatting to the svg using `div.formatSvg > svg { margin-top: auto; }` and I understand that I can set the position of the svg to relative and move it in place with `top: Npx;` but that causes the svg to [overlap the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WgUT.jpg).

My last idea is to edit the svg itself because, perhaps, there is extra space at the bottom that causes this issue but I'm doubtful.

**Relevant HTML**

```
      <div class="headerBg">
        <h1 class="headerText">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <div class="formatSvg">
          <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path d="M892.25 114.72L0 0 0 120 1200 120 1200 0 892.25 114.72z" class="shape-fill" fill="#1E1E24"
              fill-opacity="1"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
main {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.headerBg {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #d62941, #dd412f);
    height: 30rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.formatSvg {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVGs are by default `display: inline-block`. Just like `<img>`.  So, like other images, they sit on the baseline of text.  Therefore, the gap you are seeing is the space that the browser is reserving for [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender).

The fix is to change the SVG to `display: block`.

I also added a `justify-content: space-between;` to `headerBg` to force the `<h1>` to the top, and `formatSvg` to the bottom. of your 30em height div.  You may not need this bit in your final page.

```css
.headerBg {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #d62941, #dd412f);
    height: 30rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.formatSvg svg {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerBg">
  <h1 class="headerText">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <div class="formatSvg">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path d="M892.25 114.72L0 0 0 120 1200 120 1200 0 892.25 114.72z" class="shape-fill" fill="#1E1E24"
        fill-opacity="1"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```